# How can I have better control over my serial COM ports in Windows 10?

Tags: ports

I need to use a serial port with a LabVIEW program I'm making. I'm connecting the machine I'm controlling, which uses RS232, via a serial/USB converter. Windows (10) automatically installed the drivers for this converter, and I know it's working correctly.

If I look in Device Manager, it's there under Ports:

[image]

And I can successfully communicate with the machine using a Python script I happen to have:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import operator
import serial
import time

from string import *
from time import strftime

# Initialize serial
sii=serial.Serial('COM3',1200,timeout=0.5)
print( "BEGIN")

sii.write(b"T\r") 
time.sleep(1)    
temp=sii.read(100).decode("utf-8") 

sii.close()

print(temp)
print ("done")
```

I know this works, because it fetches the right information from the machine. It prints the correct "temp" value, no problems.

However, it's not connecting when I try it in LabVIEW, but my question isn't really about that. What it *is* about is, when I try it in LabVIEW, and then try the same exact python script that just worked, I get this error:

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': PermissionError(13, 'Access is denied.', None, 5)
```

So clearly, LabVIEW is still using COM3, or something. My question is, how can I "kill" that connection?

I read on another Stack Overflow thread that you can try right clicking COM3 in Device Manager, disabling it, and then enabling it, but I've tried this (without rebooting, as it asks you to do), and it doesn't work. It works again if I reboot, but that's not really a solution.

Is there some smart way to do this? I can't use Portmon because I'm using 64 bit Windows, and I've tried the methods of running it in compatibility mode, which haven't worked either. I downloaded "AccessPort", but to be honest, I don't really know what to do with it; ports are somewhat black magic to me. Ideally, I'd have some sort of program that shows what ports are connected to what applications, and let me sever those ties, but that's probably a naive view of it.

What can I do to proceed? thank you.

Comment: Not sure about the best answer, but for tips: Obviously Labview does successfully open the port and keeps it open. (Serial port access is exclusively always). Suggestions: 1) Can you try if closing Labview frees the device handle. 2) Can you check if removing/re-inserting to USB frees the device without reboot?

Comment: @OliverHeggelbacher I actually fixed the problem I was having, so maybe I should delete it... on the other hand, I am still curious about the more general question, i.e., how to monitor/control ports as opposed to black magic. Closing LV wouldn't fix it. I didn't try removing the hardware, though I suppose I could. The solution to the smaller scale problem was that I was just trying to connect to the serial in labview the wrong way (not specifying baud rate, etc), and it was hanging it there, so it was still using the port.